# How to create resizable box in SpriteKit?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'd like to create in my project resizable box like Apple Pages's boxes. 
Everything is ok (if I resize my box with an image inside my code works perfectly) except the resize of my box (with an image inside) when the box is rotated. 
I think it's a problem of algorithm but I really don't know how to correct it. Here is my code:

```
func handlePanBox(panReco:UIPanGestureRecognizer)
{
    var touchLoc: CGPoint

    touchLoc = self.scene!.convertPointFromView(panReco.locationInView(panReco.view))

    if panReco.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began
    {
            coeff_drag_x_box = touchLoc.x - box_to_touch!.position.x
            coeff_drag_y_box = touchLoc.y - box_to_touch!.position.y
    }
    else if panReco.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Changed
    {
        if (box_to_touch != nil)
        {
            var new_pos = touchLoc

            if (self.resize == true)
            {
                previous_drag_x_box = coeff_drag_x_box
                previous_drag_y_box = coeff_drag_y_box

                coeff_drag_x_box = ceil(touchLoc.x - box_to_touch!.position.x)
                coeff_drag_y_box = ceil(box_to_touch!.position.y - touchLoc.y)

                let box_index: Int! = box_to_touch!.name!.substringFromIndex(box_to_touch!.name!.endIndex.predecessor()).toInt()

                var move_x: CGFloat?
                var move_y: CGFloat?
                var size_width: CGFloat?
                var size_height: CGFloat?

                move_x = 0
                move_y = 0
                size_width = 0
                size_height = 0

                switch box_index
                    {
                case 0:
                    move_x = coeff_drag_x_box!
                    move_y = 0
                    size_width = -coeff_drag_x_box!
                    size_height = -coeff_drag_x_box!
                case 1:
                    move_x = 0
                    move_y = 0
                    size_width = 0
                    size_height = coeff_drag_y_box!
                case 2:
                    move_x = 0
                    move_y = 0
                    size_width = coeff_drag_y_box!
                    size_height = coeff_drag_y_box!
                case 3:
                    move_x = 0
                    move_y = 0
                    size_width = -(previous_drag_x_box! - coeff_drag_x_box!)
                    size_height = 0
                case 4:
                    move_x = 0
                    move_y = (coeff_drag_y_box! - previous_drag_y_box!)
                    size_width = -(coeff_drag_y_box! - previous_drag_y_box!)
                    size_height = -(coeff_drag_y_box! - previous_drag_y_box!)
                case 5:
                    move_x = 0
                    move_y = (coeff_drag_y_box! - previous_drag_y_box!)
                    size_width = 0
                    size_height = -(coeff_drag_y_box! - previous_drag_y_box!)
                case 6:
                    move_x = coeff_drag_x_box!
                    move_y = coeff_drag_x_box!
                    size_width = -coeff_drag_x_box!
                    size_height = -coeff_drag_x_box!
                case 7:
                    move_x = coeff_drag_x_box!
                    move_y = 0
                    size_width = -coeff_drag_x_box!
                    size_height = 0
                default:
                    move_x = 0
                    move_y = 0
                    size_width = 0
                    size_height = 0
                }
                if ((self.scene!.size.width + size_width!) > 100 && (self.scene!.size.height + size_height!) > 100)
                {
                    new_pos = CGPointMake(self.frame.origin.x + move_x!, self.frame.origin.y + move_y!)

                    self.frame.origin = new_pos

                    self.scene?.size = CGSizeMake(self.scene!.size.width + size_width!, self.scene!.size.height + size_height!)
                    self.frame.size = CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width + size_width!, self.frame.size.height + size_height!)

                    for node_child in self.scene!.children
                    {
                        var node_to_resize = node_child as? ImageSpriteNode

                        if (node_to_resize?.name != kBoxContactPoint && node_to_resize?.name != kPointContact && node_to_resize?.resize == true)
                        {
                            node_to_resize!.size = CGSizeMake(node_to_resize!.size.width + size_width!, node_to_resize!.size.height + size_height!)
                        }
                    }

                    self.create_contact_points(box_index)
                }
        }
    }
    else if panReco.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended
    {
        box_to_touch = nil
        self.create_contact_points(-1)
   }
}
```

Thanks!

EDIT

My image with a correct position:

[image]

After I resize it with a left to right swipe (it's ok):

[image]

My image with a rotated position:

[image]

After I resize it with a left to right swipe (it's wrong):

[image]

Comment: what exactly happens when the box is rotated? Does it make any difference if the box is rotated, then resized compared to resized, then rotated?

Comment: Hi LearnCocos2D, I edit my question with some images for explain the problem :).

Comment: Well in both cases the stretching occurs in the same direction, but if your sprite is rotated by 90 degrees it will naturally stretch up/down rather than left/right.

Comment: Looks like a job for a rotation matrix

Comment: Unfortunately my code doesn't works. Do you know where can I find a rotation matrix in swift?